# Is there a way to tag pages using the OneNote API?

Tags: c#, api, windows-store-apps, onenote

I've looked through all the OneNote API documentation and samples, and I can only find a single API call, `Create Page`, which only seems to accept HTML content for that page. I have other metadata that I want to pass in from another service, namely tags.

Is there any way to do this currently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct. As of today, the current API only supports a simple Create page method and we don't support tags yet. But we will be adding new features over time quickly; please see and comment on [our API roadmap](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/onenotedev/archive/2014/03/25/onenote-api-near-term-backlog.aspx). Also, you can submit or vote on your feature suggestion at the [OneNote API Feedback site](http://onenotedev.uservoice.com/).

-
James